# How to switch to another tab of UITabBar without touching a tab?

Tags: iphone, uitabbarcontroller

I have a tab bar setup and I want to be able to let the user change options and after the last one is selected or by pressing a button on the view, be able to automatically switch to another tab.

Simply, I have 4 tabs setup and on one, I pick an option or press a button and I want it to switch to the other tab.  I have the tab bar on the main window and 4 separate views, each as a nib file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you want a TabBarController here and not a NavigationController? For TabBars, the answer you're looking for is to set `-selectedViewController` or `-selectedIndex`. For the specific case you list, `-selectedIndex` is probably your best bet.

Comment: That worked, I just had to think through how to use it.  Thank You.